# Using a Text Box To Filter A listview that is bound to a xml

Tags: c#, wpf

`enter code here`Hey Guys, 
I am new to the wpf programming and I am having a hard time filter the list view when the user types in the text box.   when trying to filter all i get is a black listview ... I believe this is caused from the the part that I am filter is an attribute of the Node and I am not sure how to use that to filter

Example
i am trying to filter using the  baseRef  of Item

Thanks in advance

Here is my code

```
    private bool FilterItem(object obj)
    {
        Item item = obj as Item;
        if (item == null) return false;

        string textFilter = Filtertxt.Text;

        if (textFilter.Trim().Length == 0) return true; // the filter is empty - pass all items

        // apply the filter
        if (item.ItemNum.ToLower().Contains(textFilter.ToLower())) return true;
        return false;
    }

    private void Filtertxt_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)

    {
        if (!this.IsInitialized) return;    // get out of here if the window is not initialized


        /// Get the default view from the listview
        ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lviewItemsList.ItemsSource  );

        view.Filter = null;
        view.Filter = new Predicate<object>(FilterItem);
    }
My Xml struct
```

```
    <Item quantity="0" baseRef="2" desc="BLANK Item, ">
        <Material selected="0" ref="2" color="" />
        <Material selected="0" ref="2" color="" />
        <Material selected="0" ref="2" color="" />
        <Material selected="0" ref="2" color="" />
        <Material selected="0" ref="2" color="" />
        <Material selected="0" ref="2" color="" />
        <Material selected="0" ref="2" color="" />
    </Item>
    <Item quantity="0" baseRef="2" desc="BLANK Item, ">
        <Material selected="0" ref="2" color="" />
        <Material selected="0" ref="2" color="" />
        <Material selected="0" ref="2" color="" />
        <Material selected="0" ref="2" color="" />
        <Material selected="0" ref="2" color="" />
        <Material selected="0" ref="2" color="" />
        <Material selected="0" ref="2" color="" />
    </Item>
```

Xml is parsed using xpath in the xaml

```
<ListView Name="lviewItemsList" 
           MouseDoubleClick="DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource plData}, XPath=/PickList/Items/Item}" 
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Margin="87,32,63.9999999999991,61"
      KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue" Grid.Row="1"  >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="Itemlist" ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridHeaderStyle}">
                <GridViewColumn  Header="Item" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=@baseRef}"/>
                <GridViewColumn  Header ="Qty" CellTemplate="{StaticResource Qty}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Finish" CellTemplate="{StaticResource ItemFin}" Width="0"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=@desc}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

enter code here
```

the ItemNum is an item class .. i tried to pass as an object.. I am really lost here

```
internal class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private string itemNum = "";
    public string ItemNum
    {
        get { return itemNum; }
        set { itemNum = value; FirePropertyChanged("ItemNum"); }
    }
    private string itemDesc = "";
    public string ItemDesc 
    {
        get { return itemDesc; }
        set { itemDesc = value; FirePropertyChanged("ItemDesc "); }
    }

    internal class ItemCollection : ObservableCollection<Item>
    {
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How do you parse the XML? And what is `ItemNum`?

Comment: I used xpath to parse xml and ItemNum comes for the Item class .. i forgot to that add that code snip .. but its there now.. I am really lost guys.. :-(

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint inside your `FilterItem()`?

Comment: BTW, I didn't know you can use XML data inside XAML [as described here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.xpath.aspx). Thanks for making me learn about that.

Comment: I am still open to suggestion guys.. I am really lost on what else to try ..

Comment: I'm not clear what you want to do, you filter a collection of XML elements, but you try to filter in on a property (`ItemNum`) that's not in the XML at all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are binding directly to a `XmlDocument` that contains an element called `Item` and then try to filter it like it was a class you defined called `Item`. That's not right, the object your `FilterItem()` receives is just an `XmlElement`. How should the framework figure out that you want to convert it to some class that happens to have the same name? (And how it do the conversion if it managed to figure out you want that?)

Comment: Very good point and I am sorry that you had to research... I am just really lost as to how to get to the attr.. I have never coded in wpf... so this is all new to me .. the thing i can get to is the Item element .... I will continue to research ...